# AWS Device Farm doesn't run all my test classes when a test class fail

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, junit, appium, aws-device-farm

I have a Test Project using AWS Device Farm (Appium + JUnit + Android) and the project is working fine when all test classes passed, but when one test class failed the execution stops and the other test classes are not executed. When I run the test locally all my test classes are running, independent of the result of them.

This error occurr when an element is not localized on the app, for example.

Comment: You need to engage the support team to investigate this issue. Could you provide a link to your run within the [AWS Device Farm forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0)?

Comment: Are the tests dependent on each other?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246315

Comment: No, they are independent